# Random rectangle doesn't want to be in another position

Tags: java, random, draw, rectangles

What should I do to make my rectangle appear (and stay there until the app is closed)in different locations after application's restart? My code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Rectangle extends JPanel {

    Random random1 = new Random(1000);

        int x1 = random1.nextInt(1000);
        int x2 = random1.nextInt(700);
        int x3 = random1.nextInt(600);
        int x4 = random1.nextInt(400);

         protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++ ){
            int x1 = random1.nextInt(1000);
            int x2 = random1.nextInt(700);
            int x3 = random1.nextInt(600);
            int x4 = random1.nextInt(400);

            super.paintComponent(g); 

            //rectangle
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(x2, x3, x1, x4);
        }
       repaint();
        }
 }
```

For now I have a rectangle appearing every sec somewhere else. I want it to change location but after restart of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is, don't randomise the position of your rectangles within the `paintComponent` method.  This may be called any number of times during the execution of your program

```
class Rectangle extends JPanel {

    Random random1 = new Random(1000);

    private java.awt.Rectangle[] rects;

    public Rectangle() {
        rects = new java.awt.Rectangle[2];
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++ ){
            int x1 = random1.nextInt(1000);
            int x2 = random1.nextInt(700);
            int x3 = random1.nextInt(600);
            int x4 = random1.nextInt(400);
            rects[i] = new java.awt.Rectangle(x1, x2, x3, x4);
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        for(java.awt.Rectangle rect : rects){
            g2d.fill(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Call `super.paintComponent` only once, one of it's jobs is to fill the background...

Don't call `repaint` or an method that might cause `repaint` to be called from within any `paintXxx` method, this sets up a nasty infinite loop which will suck your PC into a black hole

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your Random with the different [seed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29) each time. Try

```
 Random random1 = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

When Random is initialized with the same seed, it returns the same sequence of random numbers reach time.